# Convert D3 to JQuery to append a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm working on a project that requires the use of JQuery and Ajax. However, I have mostly worked with D3.js in the past and therefore used D3 in my code to dynamically append a table. Because I couldn't really mix my D3 code with JQuery, I need to append a table in JQuery instead.

I need to append a row first, then select that row, then append the row with `'<td>'` tags and add text from an array. I wrote it as follows in D3:

```
var tableArray = []
tableArray.push(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)

var row = d3.select('tbody').append('tr');

tableArray.forEach(function(x) {

    var cell = row.append('td');
    cell.text(x);
});
```

How can I do the same thing in JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jQuery is a little rusty, but what is in the below snippet will work.  The biggest things to remember is that they way new elements are constructed differently (as full markup), and appending doesn't return the appended element, it returns the selected element that was appended to.  Somebody else may be able to give you a more efficient or idiomatic approach.

```js
var tableArray = []
tableArray.push('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5')

var tbody = $('tbody'); // get a reference to the existing tbody by CSS selector
var row = $('<tr/>'); // construct a tr element

tableArray.forEach(function(x) { // before appending to the tbody...
    var cell = ('<td>' + x + '</td>'); // construct your cells with the text inline
    row.append(cell); // and append to the row
});

tbody.append(row); // finally, append your row to the tbody
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Also, FWIW, when I was first getting started [this jQuery cheat sheet](https://oscarotero.com/jquery/) (which then just links to the docs directly) was a very helpful resource.

Comment: This works! The only problem is that it adds 2 rows instead of 1. I tried this on its own without using Ajax, but it always adds 2 identical rows. Any suggestions on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I solved it. The reason it added two rows is because it inserted another <tbody> element. I solved it by giving the tbody an id and then gave a reference to it in the code like this:
var tbody = $('#tbody');